# how many different rectangles contain the center's square on $(2k+1 x 2k+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have a paper, its size is $2k+1 \times 2k+1$ squares.

there's a painted square ($1\times1$) in the center of the page.

how many DIFFERENT rectangles can you paint that contain that painted square?

different rectangles are different in size and in place.

no idea how to approach it. i just started studying discrete and it looks like conquering the world.

Comment: Hey, it is highly prefered to use $\times$ (`\times` in LaTeX) rather than $x$ in order to denote dimensions of rectangle. I have edited this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help to think of the question as: we have a grid of squares going from "k" to "k-1" to "k-2" ... to "1" to "0" to "-1" ... to "-k+2" to "-k+1" to "-k" on both axes

Let's say that k = 3, hence 2k+1 = 7

[image]

In the smallest rectangle, which is simply the central space you assigned, the rectangle goes left 0 spaces from the center, up 0 spaces, right 0 spaces, and down 0 spaces. In the larger rectangle, we go left 2 spaces from the center, up 2 spaces, right 1 space, and down 1 space. The largest possible rectangle would go left 3 spaces, up 3 spaces, right 3 spaces, and down 3 spaces.

Turning this into a larger pattern, we see that there are 4 directions - left, up, down, right - each with the possible values of $0; 1; 2; ... k,$ and thus the total number of combinations equals $(k+1)^4$

Comment: so for grid $2k+1$ there are $(k+1)^4$ combinations?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There are $2k+2$ horizontal and $2k+2$ vertical separators, including the borders. We have to calculate the number of possible rectangles that enclose the square. So, you can consider choosing $4$ separators, which represents an unique rectangle. Keep in mind that you must choose one and only one separator from each of the four sides of the center square. You can do so in $k+1$ ways each. As all the cases are independent, the total number of rectangles would be $(k+1)^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rectangle's sides must be integer length and contain whole grid squares and not fractions of grid squares:

The rectangle has a distance from left side to center square; from right side to center; from top to center; from bottom to center.  There are k+1 choices (0 to k) for values for each of these so there are $(k+1)^4$ possible rectangles.

verify this with 3x3 grid. Label the vertices as {-2.. 1}x {-2.. 1}.  Label a rectangle as (a,b)(c,d) if the upper left is vertex (a,b) and the lower right is (c,d).  The possible rectangles are ({-2,-1},{-2,-1})({0,1},{0,1}).  That's 16 possibilities.

For an 2n+1 x 2n+1 grid the possible rectangles ({-n-1,-1}{-n-1,-1}),({0,n})({0,n}) or $(n+1)^4$ possible.